In Looker Studio, how to combine selected categories into a single row in a table?
I am working in Looker Studio, and I have the following setup:
Filters:
Company No: 1
Company Name: Heavy Truckers Inc
Selected Categories: Tires, Windshield, Brakes
Selected State: CA
How can I achieve the desired outcome in the image
Attempted Solutions:
I have tried using CASE statements and concatenation (CONCAT or TRIM) in Looker Studio calculated fields, but this only works for each row. I also considered pre-aggregating the data in the source (e.g., BigQuery) using STRING_AGG or array_to_string, but I am unsure how to dynamically update the table based on filter selections.

This is a bit complicated but doable:
I would do as you suggest and pre-aggregate in BigQuery using STRING_AGG.
Then you can follow the steps that I outlined in my answer the question "Using Array Field for Filtering Rows", or use the community plugin suggested in another answer.
